# how to hold 0,1,2 in a list using python

Tags: python, list

the a only Allowed containing 0 1 2 ,

```
a=[0,1,2]#a's max size 

if a=[0,] a += [1]  --> [0,1]
if a=[0,1] a += [1]  --> [0,1]
if a=[0,1] a += [2]  --> [0,1,2]
if a=[0,1,2] a += [1]  --> [0,1,2]
if a=[0,1,2] a += [4]  --> [0,1,2]
```

so what can i do

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: `>>> a = [0,1]; a += [1]; print a`  `>>> [0, 1, 1]` Most of these are not correct. What are you asking?

Comment: Note also that the OP wants setlike behavior, as shown by the second and fourth examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always create you own class that does what you need:
**EDIT:**

```
class LimitedList:
    def __init__(self, inputList=[]):
        self._list = []
        self.append(inputList)

    def append(self, inputList):
        for i in inputList:
            if i in [0,1,2] and i not in self._list:
                self._list += [i]
        return self._list.sort()

    def set(self, inputList=[]):
        self.__init__(inputList)

    def get(self):
        return self._list   

    def __iter__(self):
        return (i for i in self._list)

    def __add__(self, inputList):
        temp = LimitedList(self._list)
        for i in inputList:
            if i in [0,1,2] and i not in temp._list:
                temp._list += [i]
        temp._list.sort()
        return temp

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._list[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._list)




a = LimitedList([2,3,4,5,6,0]) # create a LimitedList

print a.get()  # get the LimitedList

a += [2,3,4,5,6,6,1] # use the "+" operator to append a list to your limited list

print len(a) # get the length 

print a[1]   # get the element at position 1

for i in a:  # iterate over the LimitedList
    print i
```

I added some descriptors to that you can directly use the `+` operator like you wanted, and you can also iterate over the list and use the `in` operator, get the length with `len()`, and access the elements, you can add more if you want and create you own customized list type.

For more info you can check the [Data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) page

Comment: I added some stuff to the code to make it more like what you wanted

Comment: You need to override `__iadd__`, not `__add__` to use `+=` with a custom object.

Comment: actually in this case `__add__` is more important to implement than `__iadd__`, this is because in the case where `__iadd__` is missing the method `__add__` is called instead, more over `__add__` gives you the ability to add two objects and assign them to another, which `__iadd__` can't. And this is why I used `__add__` here instead of `__iadd__`

Comment: Note that according to the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should "_Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not)._", but "_Don't use spaces around the '=' sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value._"

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something wrong:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> a += [4]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 4]
>>> _
```

Comment: the a  is only Allowed add 0,1,2 in it .  no 4

Comment: Then why are you trying to add 4 to it? Are you saying that you want to *prevent* adding numbers other than 0, 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

you need to subclass list, and modify _ _ iadd__ (at least). but I haven't yet figured out exactly how. stay tuned...